# camelot in python doesn't recognize all tables

Tags: python, parsing, python-camelot

I use camelot in python for table extraction from pdf file.
I have code as follows:

```
tables=camelot.read_pdf(r'file_to_path'
                        ,flavor='lattice',pages='1'
                        ,shift_text=['']
                        )
```

The problem is camelot doesn't recognize all tables.
I run this code to debug issue "visually"

```
camelot.plot(tables[0],kind='contour').show()
```

[image]

and got output like this.
It's clear the fourth table was not recognized. I assume that's because of different shape, I mean without columns in table only rows.

Is there any way to handle this issue?

Comment: I'm trying now to figure out how table area works. Think gonna use _bbox property of all parsed tables and find if there is any space between them and pass this space to table_area while reading pdf

Answer (score 0):

For me worked line_scale=40 as additional property while reading pdf

Comment: This resolved my issue :)